# Remove permission to create category

Tags: enterprise-1.14

I have the administrator account on my Magento shop and would like to prevent users with fewer rights to create categories.

If I go to Configuration>Permissions>Roles and strip a certain user role of the rights to manage categories, user will not be able to temper with them at all. I still want them to edit descriptions, images etc.

Is there any other way of how to:

- deny the right to create a category?
- deny the right to change sorting order of categories (using drag&drop)?

If I should do it programmatically, where do you suggest I start?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are some extensions. 
Take a look at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/restrict-customer-groups-catalog-permissions-extension.html

and

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-permissions-3906.html

The first one i check and you could write your own rights to catalog.

Hope it helps

edit: by the way, if you want to make it by your own, check alan manuals about permisions.